# Confusion about the nonlocal and global names in python

Tags: python, namespaces

So i've been reading a little in the python toturial and I stumbled upon something that I don't quite understand.

When i write the following code into the interpreter:

```
    >>> def scope_test():
    ...    def try_add():
    ...       nonlocal spam
    ...       spam = "new spam"
    ...    try:
    ...       print(spam)
    ...    except:
    ...       print("exception caught")
    ...    try_add()
    ...    print(spam)
```

I get the following error:

```
      File "<stdin>", line 3
    SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'spam' found
```

but when I run this code:

```
>>> def scope_test():
...    def try_add():
...       global spam
...       spam = "new spam"
...    try:
...       print(spam)
...    except:
...       print("exception caught")
...    try_add()
...
>>> scope_test()
exception caught
>>> spam
'new spam'
```

It runs fine.

What is the explanation to this?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement

> Names listed in a nonlocal statement, unlike those listed in a global statement, **must refer to pre-existing bindings in an enclosing scope** (the scope in which a new binding should be created cannot be determined unambiguously).

(emphasis mine). The statement after the emphasis tells you why this should be so.

With `global` if the variable does not exist then it can be made in the global scope.  So, in your example with `global` python happily creates `spam` in the global scope.

With `nonlocal`, if the variable does not exist, in which scope should it be created? There could be many scopes between the nearest enclosing scope and global. Rather than guess, `nonlocal` insists that the variable already exists. In your example using `nonlocal`, there isn't a `spam` anywhere between the enclosing scope and the global scope, so you get the error.

Comment: Ty very much :)